# How to change the visualization per page in the PDF

Tags: page

I have a document that when I open the PDF appears this in the visualization:
[image]

I want to appear like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us information on your compilation process? How do you get to the PDF file?

Comment: A priori, `\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}` but probably it will be ignored by your viewer. A posteriori, most probably you could set a "Two Page view" option  in the viewer menu or so, but anyway, depends on the viewer too.

Comment: Agreed but requester is asking for single page layout thus he'd try: `\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=SinglePage]{hyperref}` instead.

Comment: @Ivan, I do not be sure if I add what you wanted, but if not this that you want to see, please, let me know.

Comment: @Ivan What slip of the tongue! As single page is  the usual without doing anything, I answered to the opposite, haha.

Comment: @George, yes, this is what I was curious about. What I would suggest, as @Fran said: add `\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=SinglePage]{hyperref}` in your preamble and compile. If the file is displayed with two pages side by side, check options in your PDF viewer and/or try with another one. Or ask someone to check on his side. Sorry, my knowledge stops here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I will put the solution here in the case someone has the same problem.

I read the document 'READ.md' which came with the template for my thesis and there was written that the standard print of version of the PDF document was programmed to be 'twoside', then I would need change where was written 'print' by 'oneside' in the documentclass, i.e.,

> \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,index, print]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

by

> \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,index, oneside]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}